# Add element from a list of dictionary to another

Tags: python

```
dict_1 = [
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372596', 'FIRST_CALL': 't'}
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372594', 'FIRST_CALL': 'f'}
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372598', 'FIRST_CALL': 'f'}
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372599', 'FIRST_CALL': 't'}
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372602', 'FIRST_CALL': 'f'}
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372601', 'FIRST_CALL': 'f'}
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372605', 'FIRST_CALL': 'f'}
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372606', 'FIRST_CALL': 'f'}
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372607', 'FIRST_CALL': 'f'}
    ]

dict_2 = [
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372605', 'DATE': '08-10-2016 00:54:13'}
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372606', 'DATE': '08-10-2016 00:57:20'}
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372607', 'DATE': '08-10-2016 01:00:25'}
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372598', 'DATE': '11-10-2016 10:57:34'}
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372602', 'DATE': '08-10-2016 10:44:34'}
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372601', 'DATE': '21-10-2016 22:30:49'}
        {'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372594', 'DATE': '18-10-2016 14:53:34'}
]
```

I have two list of dictionaries with different length and I want to add  the ("dict_2" date) to the "dict_1" according the "INCIDENT_ID"

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: you're right , my apoligies I will keep this in mind for next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `defaultdict` from `collections` module:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(dict)
for i in zip(dict_1, dict_2):
  for j in i:
    dct[j["INCIDENT_ID"]].update(j)
solution_dict = list(dct.values())
```

So, now `solution_dict` will give you the list of dictionaries with combined pairs:

```
[ {'INCIDENT_ID' : 'SD000001372607', 'DATE': '08-10-2016 01:00:25'}
{'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372601', 'DATE': '21-10-2016 22:30:49', 'FIRST_CALL': 'f'}
{'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372606', 'DATE': '08-10-2016 00:57:20'}
{'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372598', 'DATE': '11-10-2016 10:57:34', 'FIRST_CALL': 'f'}
{'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372596', 'FIRST_CALL': 't'}
{'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372594', 'DATE': '18-10-2016 14:53:34', 'FIRST_CALL': 'f'}
{'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372605', 'DATE': '08-10-2016 00:54:13', 'FIRST_CALL': 'f'}
{'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372599', 'FIRST_CALL': 't'}
{'INCIDENT_ID': 'SD000001372602', 'DATE': '08-10-2016 10:44:34', 'FIRST_CALL': 'f'} ]
```